# document.querySelectorAll not defined

Tags: meteor

I am following a calculator tutorial from here: http://thecodeplayer.com/walkthrough/javascript-css3-calculator

However I am using nitrous as the IDE and Meteor. In this part of the code in the js file:

```
// Get all the keys from document
var keys = **document.querySelectorAll**("#calculator span");
var operators = ['+', '-', 'x', '÷'];
var decimalAdded = false;
```

The 'document.querySelector All' part comes up with a not defined error. I have tried replacing it with the more Meteor friendly 'template. find' however then it just says that template is not defined. Any help would be very much appreciated. :)

Comment: `var keys = document.querySelectorAll('#calculator span');` should look like this or is this stackoverflow bad formating

Comment: where is this part of code located? server/client? in a template helper? more information please..

Comment: Make sure you add that inside a `Template.my_template_name.onRendered()`

Comment: Mark it is bad formatting, apologies